# Google analytics campaign reports not showing for mobile app tracking

Tags: ios, mobile, google-analytics

How can I see campaign reports for mobile app tracking?

For my web property the acquisition menu includes reports for campaigns, traffic, channels and more. But for my mobile app google analytics only shows new users, app market place, and google play under the acquisition reports.

The iOS SDK does include tracking [campaigns](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/campaigns).

Any idea how to get campaign, channel and traffic reports for mobile apps?

Comment: I presume you solved this problem. Any chance you want to share with us how you did it so we can give this question an answer?

Comment: I was not able to resolve this a year a half ago and moved on.  Maybe google makes it available now but since I am not currently using google analytics I am not sure.